# Generating unlimited labels

Tags: asp.net, comments

I coded for a comments page. Its working fine but all the `SELECTED` records are being displayed using `Response.Write(dr[0].ToString());` But using `Response.Write` we cannot manage them in orderly manner. So, I decided to display records in `Labels` but I am not interested to use pagination. So, now to automatically add a new `Set` of `Labels` (i.e. a `set` is a set of labels name, email, website and comments) on every update of records?

I also tried using `Labels` instead of `Response.Write` but in Labels only last record is being displayed.

Please tell me how to display each record in each set of `labels`.

My code follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;

public partial class comment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=test_com;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=*****;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);

            MyConnection.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select name, email, website, comments from awm_comments", MyConnection);
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows == false)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Response.Write(dr[0].ToString());
                Response.Write(dr[1].ToString());
                Response.Write(dr[2].ToString());
                Response.Write(dr[3].ToString());

                /* test using labels. Being displayed only last record. 
                Label1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                Label2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                Label4.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                */
            }
    }
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = tb_name.Text;
        string email = tb_email.Text;
        string website = tb_website.Text;
        string comment = tb_comment.Text;

        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=test_com;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=******;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO awm_comments(name, email, website, comments, notify)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", MyConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@alternate_email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ipaddr", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = website;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@security_question", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = comment;
        if (cb_notify.Checked == true)
        {
            int not = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@security_question", OdbcType.Int, 11).Value = not;
        }
        else if (cb_notify.Checked == false)
        {
            int not = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@security_question", OdbcType.Int, 11).Value = not;
        }
        MyConnection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you scratch most of what you have and use a repeater.

Follow the following basic how to use a repeater article http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Label1.Text += dr[0].ToString() + "<br/>";
Label2.Text += dr[1].ToString() + "<br/>";
Label3.Text += dr[2].ToString() + "<br/>";
Label4.Text += dr[3].ToString() + "<br/>";
```

`+=` operator for appending text to existing text of `Labels` and `<br/>` for line break

Comment: Awesome. This is working fine but all the records of First Label are displayed in order then follows second. I need in a SET manner.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a repeater control bound to the datasource that retrieves the records you are currently getting using your OdbcConnection? Then use their indexes or some other tag to iterate throught them.

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/repeater.aspx